# Joomla Module Chrome module index

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I am using Joomla Module Chrome to style a sidebar. Is it possible to find out if the current module is the last module in the modules.php file?

Basically i want to find the current module's Index in the CountModules function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to add extra CSS to the last sidebar item, right? I don't use Joomla myself, but if possible, you could add an `id="last-item"` attribute to the last module element. Then in the CSS  you could define whatever you want to the last item using `#last-item`.

Also if you just wanted to add a line or something to the bottom (as supposed to something like a background colour) you could add another module to the bottom just containing that. It's a bit messy but it could work.